# Erro(Bitmap size too big) ao usar Timage em thread firemonkey android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Uso essa função para gerar thumbs das imagens no sistema:

```
procedure converte_jpg(Bitmap: TBitmap; Stream: TMemoryStream);
var
  surf: TBitmapSurface;
  saveParams : TBitmapCodecSaveParams;
begin
  surf := TBitmapSurface.Create;

  try
    surf.Assign(Bitmap);
    saveParams.Quality:= 20;
    if not TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(Stream, surf, '.jpg',@saveParams) 
    then
      raise EBitmapSavingFailed.Create(SBitmapSavingFailed);
  finally
    Surf.Free;
  end;
end;
```

chamo ela assim

```
img.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(imagem);
converte_jpg(img.Bitmap,thumb_img);
```

o resultado da função é um TMemoryStream que eu salvo no banco de dados, a função funciona normalmente na thread principal, porém, quando coloco ela dentro de um thread anonima, da o seguinte erro

> Bitmap size too big.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta enfileirar a thread então:

```
TThread.Queue(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    img.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(imagem);
    converte_jpg(img.Bitmap,thumb_img);
  end);
```

Uma alternativa simples e que resolve problema de estouro de memória de BLOBs seria converter essa imagem para uma string Base64 ao invés de gerar um TMemoryStream e salvar essa string no banco de dados, daí quando for ler a imagem, basta converter de base64 para bitmap, quando for gravar, basta converter de bitmap para base64.

Código de David Hefferman, disponível em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909096/convert-base64-to-bitmap

```
function Base64FromBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap): string;
var
  Input: TBytesStream;
  Output: TStringStream;
begin
  Input := TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(Input);
    Input.Position := 0;
    Output := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ASCII);
    try
      Soap.EncdDecd.EncodeStream(Input, Output);
      Result := Output.DataString;
    finally
      Output.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Input.Free;
  end;
end;

function BitmapFromBase64(const base64: string): TBitmap;
var
  Input: TStringStream;
  Output: TBytesStream;
begin
  Input := TStringStream.Create(base64, TEncoding.ASCII);
  try
    Output := TBytesStream.Create;
    try
      Soap.EncdDecd.DecodeStream(Input, Output);
      Output.Position := 0;
      Result := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        Result.LoadFromStream(Output);
      except
        Result.Free;
        raise;
      end;
    finally
      Output.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Input.Free;
  end;
end;
```